# Проблема с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть код, который перенаправляет с http://site.ru/system/user.php на http://site.ru/user.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^system/user\.php$ /user.php [R=301]
```

Проблема такова: когда он перенаправляет на `user.php`, показывает `404 not found`, мол страницы не существует, хотя на самом деле это и есть `system/user.php`. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить /user.php на user.php

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^system/user\.php$ user.php [R=301]`

Или добавить строчку вверх: RewriteBase / и ничего не менять

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^system/user\.php$ /user.php [R=301]`

Comment: @Зоркий, 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^system/user\.php$ /user.php [R=301]

Не помогает. И первый варинт тоже..

Comment: Еще какие либо правила есть в файле?

Comment: @Зоркий, нет. Только вот эти..